# Error opening video file with openCV cv2VideoCapture

Tags: python, opencv, video, ffmpeg

I have a video file here /data/out.mp4 and its copy /data/out. 
I'm on Osx Sierra with Xcode 8.

Open video with mp4 extension is ok but get error with no extension or any other format.

I tryed opencv 2.4 and latest 3.2 from git.
Compiled with ffmpeg release/2.0 and also tryed release/3.0

**With opencv version 3.2:**

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 30 2016, 19:40:32)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'3.2.0-dev'
>>> cv2.__file__
'/Users/johndoe/work/myproject/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so'
```

**If video have extension:**

```
>>> v=cv2.VideoCapture('/data/out.mp4')
>>> v.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
61117.0
```

**If video have no extension:**

```
>>> v=cv2.VideoCapture('/data/out')
VIDEOIO(cvCreateFileCapture_AVFoundation (filename)): raised unknown C++ exception!

>>> v.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
0.0
```

My FFmpeg configure:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr \
--bindir=/usr/local/bin/ \
--shlibdir=/usr/lib64 \
--datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg \
--incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg \
--libdir=/usr/lib64 \
--mandir=/usr/share/man \
--extra-cflags='-O2 -g' \
--extra-version=rpmfusion \
--enable-bzlib  \
--enable-nonfree \
--enable-libopenjpeg \
--enable-libx264  \
--enable-avfilter \
--enable-postproc \
--enable-pthreads \
--disable-static \
--enable-shared \
--enable-gpl \
--enable-runtime-cpudetect \
--arch=x86_64
```

My opencv CMAKE:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/johndoe/work/myproject/venv/local/ \
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-D PYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH=/Users/johndoe/work/myproject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages \
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
-D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/Users/johndoe/work/myproject/venv/bin/python \
-D WITH_CUDA=OFF ..
```

I tryed various other formats reencoding my original video (ie: ffmpeg -i out.mp4 out.asf) :

```
>>> v=cv2.VideoCapture('/data/out.avi')
VIDEOIO(cvCreateFileCapture_AVFoundation (filename)): raised unknown C++ exception!

>>> v=cv2.VideoCapture('/data/out.flv')
VIDEOIO(cvCreateFileCapture_AVFoundation (filename)): raised unknown C++ exception!

>>> v=cv2.VideoCapture('/data/out.asf')
VIDEOIO(cvCreateFileCapture_AVFoundation (filename)): raised unknown C++ exception!
```

Comment: So your question is "How to make opencv infer file type, if the file has no extension?"

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV may use different Capture API. One can enforce API, by specifying it as a second parameter to VideoCapture():

```
v = cv2.VideoCapture('/data/out', cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)
```

I've tried cv2.VideoCapture() with both file having extension and without extension and it works fine, using default Capture API. Note, that I'm on OS X El Captain, and using python 3.5.2 with OpenCV 3.1 all installed with conda (Anaconda).

Comment: This does remove the original error but still doesn't work getting the frame count with cv2.CAP_PRO_FRAME_COUNT returns 0.0 despite the video being 2M and readable in VLC.

Comment: Try to get and show couple of frames from the file. This is to check, that file was actually loaded / parsed.

Comment: @kollo any thing figured out on this yet.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error, but finally fixed it on my own! Please see image below. In my errors, I found a line that said "Name CamTwist" —— CamTwist was an application/plug-in that I installed months ago, which was clogging the main access to my webcam. I had already uninstalled the application a few weeks ago, but there were some leftover files on my hard-drive, so I went to my Finder > Home > Search: CamTwist, and behold! There were two files with CamTwist included, so I threw them in the trash can, emptied that thing REAL quick, re-ran my code, and WALLAH! I was so happy.

I'd recommend searching for that "Name" line. Perhaps you, too, have installed some silly webcam app that's clogging access!

[Click to view screenshot of my terminal code and where I found the core issue for my bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WL7O2.png)

Answer (score -1):

I had this same problem, please put the absolute media file path.